# Radio icon disappears on selection - using Material UI

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, radio-group

I have used the RadioGroup component of material UI. When a radio button is selected, the radio icon(rounded) disappears and only the label remains.

```
const [env,setEnv]=React.useState('Development')

<Grid container spacing={3}>
  <Grid item xs={3}>
    <Card className={classes.card} elevation={1}>
      <CardContent>
        <form noValidate onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
          <FormControl >
            <FormLabel >Select Environment</FormLabel>
            <RadioGroup value={env} onChange={(e) => setEnv(e.target.value)}>
              <FormControlLabel value='Development' control={<Radio />} label="Development" />
              <FormControlLabel value='Stage' control={<Radio />} label="Stage" />
              <FormControlLabel value='Production' control={<Radio />} label="Production" />
            </RadioGroup>
          </FormControl>
        </form>
      </CardContent>
    </Card>
  </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Comment: I have tested your code in a sample form, perfectly fine just make sure you closed the parent Grid..

Comment: Dependency on multiple files. It will be difficult to include. However, I just tried adding background color in RadioGroup and then I am able to view it. So it looks when I click , it turns complete white and so it disappears. Still debugging...

Comment: @VaibhavGidde Thanks. So, it looks may be some inherited css is creating problem. Not sure though

Comment: If there is a css problem, try zIndex property for card component class

Comment: @VaibhavGidde - I followed the approach of overriding the radio icon theme.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried in this way:
I did it in this way:

```
const theme = {
  overrides: {
    MuiRadio: {
      root: {
        color: 'green',
      },
      colorSecondary: {
        '&$checked': {
          color: 'green',
        },
      },
    },
  },
}

const muiTheme = createMuiTheme(theme)
```

I can now change the color of radio icon as per my need :)